# Render action in two different controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

I have a list of `StockMovements` and an ajax picking list of `stock_movements`.

My application has a ajax search with `will_paginate` and `elasticsearch`. To add list to picking list I put the following code in each column of StockMovement's list:

```ruby
<%= button_to 'Retornar', linha_devolucaos_path(stock_movement_id: stock_movement.id, page: params[:page]), class: 'btn btn-mini' if !stock_movement.back and !stock_movement.linha_devolucaos.present? %>
```

It updates the picking list with a js response of that item:

```js
$('#romaneio').html("<%=j render @devolucao %>")
```

In ajax it runs fine, but doesn't hide the `retornar` button because that div isn't updated. I know I need to request the js response of my `StockMovement#index` action, but how and where I call that action and how to pass the params?

LinhaDevolucao#create Controller

```
def create
@devolucao = current_devolucao_romaneio
stock_movement = StockMovement.find(params[:stock_movement_id])
@devolucao.add_stock_movement(stock_movement.id)

respond_to do |format|
  if @devolucao.save
    format.html { redirect_to stock_movements_path(page: params[:page]), notice: 'Linha devolucao was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @linha_devolucao, status: :created, location: @linha_devolucao }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @linha_devolucao.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

LinhaDevolucao/create.js

```
$('#romaneio').html("<%=j render @devolucao %>");
```

And then I need to update my current StockMovement List to hide the "retornar" button of the lines that're already in the linha_devolucao. My StockMovement#index action does the job, but how and where I redirect to this action and render the js response?

```
$("#equipments-table").html("<%=j render("equipments")  %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"<%=j render @devolucao %>")
```

I think: It's not good, you must render custom view in StockMovements folder. For example:

```
<%=j render 'devolcao' %>
```

In this file you can create your cycle with @devolucao.

But I don't know your view's files.

Comment: I have a partial called 'devolucaos/_devolucao.html.erb'. The div romaneio is fine, but I need to update the div that holds the 'retornar' button so it should hide the ones that's already in the pickinglist.